# how to efficiently compare two dictionaries of lists of strings using difflib?

Tags: python, numpy, difflib

I have two large dictionaries of lists. All the elements of the lists are strings. I want to compare all against all and compute their respective similarity - but the naive way I use is obviously very slow and does not scale at all:

```
import numpy as np
import difflib  

first_dict = {"first1" : ["aa", "bb","cc", "dd"], "first2" : ["ff", "gg"]}

second_dict = {"second1" : ["cc", "dd", "jj", "aa", "bb"], "second2" : ["ff", "gg"], "second3" : ["hh", "ii"]}  

mat = np.empty((len(second_dict), len(first_dict)))

for i, second in enumerate(second_dict.keys()):
    for j, first in enumerate(first_dict.keys()):
        sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, sorted(first_dict[first]), sorted(second_dict[second]))
        mat[i, j] = sm.ratio() 

print(mat)
```

is there a clever way to speed this up?

Comment: It's already pretty fast in my opinion? What do you mean by scaling?

Comment: @tristan, what is your maximum size of first and second dicts?

Comment: @ferdy both the dicts have about 20k entries...

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems legit. I did a couple of little tweaks that would shave off a couple of microseconds per loop:

1. No need for the two `sorted` calls because `difflib` can calculate an order-indifferent comparison with `quick_ratio` (Checkout the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) for the difference between `ratio`, `quick_ratio`, and `real_quick_ratio`).
2. No need for the `enumerate` to access `mat` by `i` and `j`.
3. Removed the access of the list through index `first_dict[index]` and `second_dict[index]`

```py
def naive_ratio_comparison(first_dict, second_dict):
    mat = []
    for second in second_dict.values():
        for first in first_dict.values():
            sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, first, second)
            mat.append(sm.quick_ratio())
    result = np.resize(mat, (len(second_dict), len(first_dict)))
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you - very much - i did not know, that quick_ratio exists!

Answer (score 2):

If one dict has `M` entries and the other `N`, then you're going to have to do `M*N` `.ratio()` calls. There's no way around that, and it's going to be costly.

However, you can easily arrange to do only `M+N` sorts instead of (as shown) `M*N` sorts.

For computing `.ratio()`, the most valuable hint is in the docs:

> `SequenceMatcher` computes and caches detailed information about the second sequence, so if you want to compare one sequence against many sequences, use `set_seq2()` to set the commonly used sequence once and call `set_seq1()` repeatedly, once for each of the other sequences.

Putting that all together:

```
firsts = list(map(sorted, first_dict.values())) # sort these only once

sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None)
for i, second in enumerate(second_dict.values()):
    sm.set_seq2(sorted(second))
    for j, first in enumerate(firsts):
        sm.set_seq1(first)
        mat[i, j] = sm.ratio()
```

That should deliver exactly the same results. To minimize the number of expensive `.set_seq2()` calls, it would - of course - be best to arrange for the shorter dict to be called "second_dict".

### Alternative

It's worth asking whether you actually want `difflib` at all here. What are you really trying to accomplish? Nothing here looks at the contents of the strings of at all, beyond noting whether or not two strings are equal.

Perhaps what you really want is a different measure of "similarity". For example, one based on how many strings two lists have in common. If so, here's a way that doesn't use `difflib`:

```
    from collections import Counter
    cfirst = [(Counter(v), len(v)) for v in first_dict.values()]
    csecond = [(Counter(v), len(v)) for v in second_dict.values()]
    for i, (second, n2) in enumerate(csecond):
        for j, (first, n1) in enumerate(cfirst):
            mat[i, j] = sum((first & second).values()) * 2 / (n1 + n2)
```

That gives the same results on the specific example you gave, but is significantly cheaper to compute. The "ratio" computed here is the the total number of strings the two lists have in common, divided by the total number of strings in the two lists. That's easy to compute using `Counter`s directly.

@Bilal Qandeel's answer suggested using `difflib`'s `.quick_ratio()` instead, which happens to compute something similar under the covers. But that `.quick_ratio()` is order-independent is an undocumented implementation detail, and it's quicker to leave `difflib` out of it entirely if that is good enough.

NOTE: starting with Python 3.10,

```
            mat[i, j] = sum((first & second).values()) * 2 / (n1 + n2)
```

can be replaced by

```
            mat[i, j] = (first & second).total() * 2 / (n1 + n2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this is excellent!
The implementation using counter is exactly what i was looking for but did not figure it out on my own since i was too set on using difflib. THANKS!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped :-) See new note at the end for a spelling simplification made possible by the new `Counter.total()` method introduced in Python 3.10.